# Laravel 3, sessions flash, flush and forget doesnt work between methods

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-3

In my job we have a system that is running on Laravel 3.0, and we have an issue when we use the `Session::flash('whatever')`, if we keep in the same function or method, for example, `post_new(){}`.
The session variable is deleted at the end of the next execution as it should do, but if we use a `redirect()->with()` or `Session::flash('something'); return redirect()`, it does not work.

The session is stored but never deleted, even more, we cannot delete it from the other method that the same session created even if we use `Session::flush()` or `Session::forget()`.

Do you have any experience with this issue? We didn't configure the project, it was already running when we started working here, we are just adding functions.

Comment: If I recall correctly there was an issue with laravel 3 redirects not writing back to the session when they were triggered.

Comment: Thanks for comment, is there anything we can do to fix it?